# Postman IllegalArgumentException: Target object must not be null",

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postman

I am new at Postman. When I enter some info on postman I got an error below;

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-08-28T07:18:24.540+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Target object must not be null; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object must not be null",
    "path": "/userRight/create"
}
```

```
@RequestMapping(value = "userRight/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    // @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<CreateUserRightResponseType> createUserRight(@RequestBody CreateUserRightRequestType request)
            throws UserRightException {

        CreateUserRightResponseType response = new CreateUserRightResponseType();

        try {
            userRightService.createUserRight(request.getUserRightType());
            response.setStatus(ResponseStatusCodes.SUCCESS);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);

        } catch (UserRightException e) {
            response.setStatus(ResponseStatusCodes.ERROR);
            response.setErrorMessage(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

    }

}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Status 500 shows that issue is with your rest service..kindly check that or share the code if required

Comment: please update your question with rest service code

Comment: Also, please update your question with full stacktrace and with the request you're sending from Postman.

Comment: In most cases this error occurs when you're not performing the POST request correctly using Postman. Can you please share a picture of how you have Postman setup?

Comment: {
 "login_name": "deneme@deneme.com",
 "vendor_id": "dx",
 "is_active": "T",
 "access_right_code": "root"
}

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your postman ? Also, looking at the above comment - Are you setting the content-type to application-json in the header tab ?

Comment: yes, it is application/json

Comment: A screenshot of postman should help !